# Typescript in react JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using `react-select-async-paginate`:

```js
async function loadOptions(search, loadedOptions, { page }) {
  const response = await fetch(`/awesome-api-url/?search=${search}&page=${page}`);
  const responseJSON = await response.json();

  return {
    options: responseJSON.results,
    hasMore: responseJSON.has_more,
    additional: {
      page: page + 1,
    },
  };
}

<AsyncPaginate
  value={value}
  loadOptions={loadOptions}
  onChange={setValue}
  additional={{
    page: 1,
  }}
/>
```

How to apply the typescript for this code: `(search, loadedOptions, { page })` taking into account that [these](https://github.com/vtaits/react-select-async-paginate/blob/master/packages/react-select-async-paginate/src/types.ts)  are the types?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-paginate-forked-qiizl?file=/src/SelectAsyncPaginate.tsx

Answer (score 1):

As you can [see](https://github.com/vtaits/react-select-async-paginate/blob/ec82c16af577bc357f2c596a89207b4cd071b577/packages/react-select-async-paginate/src/types.ts#L75) `loadOptions` type is `LoadOptions<OptionType, Additional>`.

That's how you should type your `loadOptions` function

```
const loadOptions: LoadOptions<any, {page: number}> = ...
```

You should replace `any` with the actual option's type (you can figure it from the API response)

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-paginate-forked-00k7m?file=/src/SelectAsyncPaginate.tsx

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546842/add-typescript-types-on-select-in-onchange-function-from-reactjs

Comment: Looks like you got some comments there. Let me know if you need more help