# Add Typescript types to react-select onChange function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am using the [`CreatableSelect` component](https://react-select.com/creatable) from React Select in my application but I am having trouble adding Typescript types.

All I want to do is to change `any` from `handleChange = (value: any)` with the right types. I used this  `const handleChange = (value: { label: any; value: any }[]) => {` but it does not work.

How can I change `any` type to the right type?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-9tsfp?file=/example.js

```js
export default class CreatableInputOnly extends Component<*, State> {
  state = {
    inputValue: "",
    value: []
  };
  handleChange = (value: any) => {
    console.log(value, "test");
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: string) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue });
  };
  handleKeyDown = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
    if (!inputValue) return;
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Enter":
      case "Tab":
        console.group("Value Added");
        console.log(value);
        console.groupEnd();
        this.setState({
          inputValue: "",
          value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)]
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        components={components}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        isClearable
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={false}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Type something and press enter..."
        value={value}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you hover over `onChange` prop you will see how it's typed: `onChange: (newValue: ValueType<OptionType, IsMulti>,`

Comment: You could also inline the function and Typescript will infer the type `onChange={(value) => {
    console.log(value, "test");
    this.setState({ value });
  };}`

Answer (score 3):

The specific types depend on a generic type parameter `OptionType`.  The default type for `OptionType` is the `{ label: string; value: string }` type which you are using.

**I believe that the issue you are having is due to incorrect/outdated type packages in your environment.**

---

In a [new CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-ts-callbacks-8j483?file=/src/App.tsx), where I installed `@types/react-select`, the definition for the `onChange` function is:

```
onChange?: (value: ValueType<OptionType, IsMulti>, action: ActionMeta<OptionType>) => void;
```

This `ValueType` utility type basically says that on a single select you have either an option or `null` and on on multiple select you have an `array` of options.

```
export type ValueType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase, IsMulti extends boolean> = IsMulti extends true
    ? OptionsType<OptionType>
    : OptionType | null;

export type OptionsType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase> = ReadonlyArray<OptionType>;
```

---

I'm not sure how your linked sandbox is enqueing its types because the `@types/react-select` package is not included in the `package.json`.  But if I "Go To Definition" I get a definition from a `/sandbox/node_modules/@types/react-select/src` file.  These are the types that I see:

```
onChange?: (value: ValueType<OptionType>, action: ActionMeta) => void;

export type ValueType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase> = OptionType | OptionsType<OptionType> | null | undefined;

export type OptionsType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase> = ReadonlyArray<OptionType>;
```

---

**So what's the difference?**

In the first case, we know that since you have a multi-select you will always receive an array of options.

In the second case there is no `IsMulti` flag, so the types state that you could receive an array or a single option (or `null` or `undefined`).  Your `handleChange` function can only handle an array, so it can't be used as an `onChange` handler since it can't handle all of the possible arguments that it might receive.

---

With the correct package types, what you tried before is almost correct.  The only issue is that the array is `readonly`, so we have to make sure that we can accept a `ReadonlyArray` in both the handler and the state.

FYI these functions aren't being called where I would intuitively expect.  `handleChange` is called when removing a tag but not when adding a new one by pressing enter.  So you'll want to check out the docs and/or play with the various callbacks.  There are [six props which are only on `CreatableSelect`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-select/src/Creatable.d.ts) -- two settings and four callbacks.

This should fix all of your Typescript errors, using `@types/react-select` 4.0.13 and `react-select` 4.3.0:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";
import { ActionMeta, InputActionMeta } from "react-select";

const components = {
  DropdownIndicator: null
};

const createOption = (label: string) => ({
  label,
  value: label
});

type MyOption = ReturnType<typeof createOption>;
// or type MyOption = { label: string;  value: string; }

interface MyState {
  inputValue: string;
  value: ReadonlyArray<MyOption>;
}

interface MyProps {
  // are there any?
}

export default class CreatableInputOnly extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  state: MyState = {
    inputValue: "",
    value: []
  };
  handleChange = (
    value: ReadonlyArray<MyOption>,
    meta: ActionMeta<MyOption>
  ) => {
    console.log("value", value, "meta", meta);
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: string, meta: InputActionMeta) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue });
  };
  handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
    if (!inputValue) return;
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Enter":
      case "Tab":
        console.group("Value Added");
        console.log(value);
        console.groupEnd();
        this.setState({
          inputValue: "",
          value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)]
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        components={components}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        isClearable
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={false}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Type something and press enter..."
        value={value}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-ts-callbacks-8j483?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1836)

Comment: could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953930/apply-types-in-react-ant-design