# Apply types in React ant design

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using Table from antd design. And, I want to type `onChange` function that is passed as param in Table component.

```
const change = (
  pagination: TablePaginationConfig,
  filters: Record<string, Key[] | null>,
  sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[]
) => {};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table onChange={change} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

The issue is that I can't import `RecordType`. How to type properly this code without using `any`? Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4150-forked-xk5sg?file=/index.tsx:1543-1837).

Comment: I don't see that ant design exports a type ```RecordType```. This is just a typescript generic. You need to provide your own type. Like this: ```sorter: SorterResult<MyType> | SorterResult<MyType>[]```

Comment: @TwoHorses, could you show what do you mean, please?

Comment: Create a type for the data that you pass to ```dataSource``` prop (for instance ```MyType```). Then use it in the ```SorterResult```

Comment: @TwoHorses, but how to proceed if in my `change` function i want to use  for example: `setData(sorter.field)`. Typescript says that : `Property 'field' does not exist on type 'SorterResult<MyType> | SorterResult<MyType>[]'.` How to solve?

Comment: Thats because you declared  ```sorter``` as ```SorterResult<MyType> | SorterResult<MyType>[]``` which can be an array, arrays dont have ```field```.

Comment: You can do ```setData((sorter as SorterResult<MyType>).field)``` for now to test it.

Comment: @TwoHorses, could you sjow here https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-antd4150-forked-ie0o5?file=/index.tsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230758/discussion-between-asking-and-two-horses).

Comment: @TwoHorsesi get , i get   Property 'field' does not exist on type 'SorterResult<{ field: string; order: string; }>[]'.

Comment: @TwoHorses, could you show me on the sanbox how to change the code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to declare the type of `change` explicitly, the generics of `SorterResult` is the type of dataSource item, and you can declare the type of `change` implicitly in two ways.

**1. Pass generics to table element**

```js
type TDataItem = {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
}

<Table<TDataItem> onChange={()=>{}} columns={columns} dataSource={[]} />,
```

**2. Pass generics to columns:**

```js
import { ColumnProps } from 'antd/lib/table';

...

type TDataItem = {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
}

...

const columns: ColumnProps<TDataItem>[] = [

<Table onChange={()=>{}} columns={columns} dataSource={[]} />,
```

Comment: i tried to create a demo here, could you help https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-antd4150-forked-ie0o5?file=/index.tsx

Comment: i tryed `SorterResult<{field: string, order: string}` but it does not help

Comment: , i get   Property 'field' does not exist on type 'SorterResult<{ field: string; order: string; }>[]'.

Comment: Now you can take a look. I have added some keys in the data, and declare the type of dataItem

Comment: If you don't want to declare type of dataItem like above, you can try this one:
_________________________________________________________________________

`type dataItem = typeof data[0]`

Comment: sry, Idk how to edit ur code in your condsandbox, so I forked.
https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-antd4150-forked-lzvxv?file=/index.tsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230761/discussion-between-zixicat-and-asking).

Answer (score 0):

You just want to let the Table component know what type of data are you passing to it to help with the types.

If you were to update your function, you can use your current data's shape as your type and your `Table` should point to the correct **RecordType**

```
type TableData = typeof data[0];
const change = (
  pagination: TablePaginationConfig,
  filters: Record<string, Key[] | null>,
  sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[]
) => {};
return <Table<TableData> columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have given the correct Column type

```
const columns: ColumnsType<TDataItem> = [...]
```

You can try - `sorter?.['field']`

So, in the onChange function -

```
onChange: (pagination, filter, sorter) => {
  console.log(sorter?.['field'])
}
```